# anyone can help to explain the count(*) in the where clause

Tags: sql

When I am doing this problem, write a SQL query to get the nth highest salary from the Employee table.

I saw a solution below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) 
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    RETURN (
            # Write your MySQL query statement below.
            SELECT e1.Salary
            FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Salary FROM Employee) e1
            WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                   FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Salary FROM Employee) e2  
                   WHERE e1.Salary < e2.Salary) = N - 1          
           );
END
```

Question: I do not understand the `count(*)` in the where clause. I use an example of salary list like (500, 400, 300, 200, 100).

I count the number of e2.Salary > e1.Salary, but the result is (4,3,2,1,0) not (0,1,2,3,4) which is the right number for N-1.

So could anyone explain the logic there?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `ORDER BY` to order the data?

Answer (score 3):

In fact, the `count(*)` expression is not in where clause, it is in `select` clause of subquery which is used in `where` clause, which is syntactically ok. Your query actually says "give me such salary for which there exists N-1 higher salaries". Anyway it looks too complex and difficult to understand. This is good case for using [nth_value](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-nth_value-function/) window function or at least `order by ... limit ... offset`, no nested subquery is needed here.